# Find all polynomials whose coefficients are $\{0,\ldots, n\}$ and all roots are real

Tags: polynomials, roots

Find all polynomials $P \in \mathbb{Z}[x],\;\deg(P)= n$ s.t.:

$(1)$ All roots of $P$ are real

$(2)$ The set of coefficients of polynomial $P$ is equal to $\{0, 1, ..., n\}$

Due to Vieta's formula, I have realized that the coefficient $a_0$ (the one that is with $x^0$) must be equal to $0$.

Comment: Why not start by doing this for small $n$?   That might suggest a pattern.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That is not a counter example. The coefficients must have all of the numbers 0,1,2,...,n exactly once.

Comment: @JohnLingard Yes, I realised that after writing the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that every polynomial satisfying the two conditions must be positive on $\mathbb{R}$, therefore all its roots are negative. 
Now Let's write $P=X\prod_{1\leq k \leq n-1}(X+a_{i})$

we have $(\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n-1} a_{k})((\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n-1} \frac1{a_{k}})\geq (n-1)^2$, therefore $(\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n-1} a_{k})((\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n-1} (\prod_{1 \leq j \leq n-1} a_{j})\frac1{a_{k}})\geq (n-1)^2(\prod_{1 \leq j \leq n-1} a_{j})$

Notice that the coefficient of $x^{n-1} $(respectively $x$) in the expansion of $P=\prod_{1\leq k \leq n-1}(x+a_{i})$
is $(\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n-1} a_{k})$ (respectively $(\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n-1} (\prod_{1 \leq j \leq n-1} a_{j})\frac1{a_{k}})$ ). therefore there product is inferior to $n(n-1)$

but this implies $ \frac{n}{n-1}\geq (\prod_{1 \leq j \leq n-1} a_{j}) $ 
therefore being the coefficient of $x^{1}$ in $P$ the quantity  $ (\prod_{1 \leq j \leq n-1} a_{j}) =1 or 2$. it equals 2 if and only if n=2 i.e $P=X(X+2)$ .

I think that if you push the reasoning and consider the coefficient of $x^{k}$ times the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ you can prove that this is the only solution for $n\geq2$.

Comment: There are n + 1 coefficients, and when we ignore the 0, we have n coefficients. So I guess the range of the sum should be 1 ... n?

Comment: And also, when you use the sum and product (with j and k) you never use j, is that on purpose or just a mistake in typing?

Comment: NO Mr.John , the range is n-1 , because we have n-1 roots that are strictly negative

Comment: i use k in the sum , and j in the product that I wanted to insert inside the sum to distinguish it for k , the product is just a constant .

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I thought that a1,...,an are coefficients, not roots.

Comment: But when you say (product from j = 1...n - 1) a_k. Shouldn't it write a_j instead?

Comment: ah yes my bad let me change that